# Validation Rule to only Fire when Stage ISCHANGED

Tags: validation-rule

I have a validation rule that I only want to fire if the stage is changed. So if the opportunity is already in that stage I don't want the rule to fire if I change other values in the opp.  I've used the ISCHANGED(StageName) functionality - and it is still firing on existing opps when I'm not making changes to the stage name.

```
Record_Type_Name__c="A" &&
ISBLANK(Multipicklist_Field) &&
(ISCHANGED(StageName) &&
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Needs Analysis") || ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Decision Making"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to separate the logic out a bit like this:

```
ISBLANK(Multipicklist_Field) &&
( ISCHANGED(StageName) &&
  ( ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Needs Analysis") || 
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Decision Making")
  )
)
```

I did it and I could see another bracket was needed - I've added.

Comment: found I left of a closing bracket... fixed

Comment: The vital component here was putting parenthesis around the stagename checks here. In your (OP's) original formula, the structure was making it so that Salesforce was evaluating the `ISCHANGED(StageName) && ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Needs Analysis")` part first rather than evaluating `ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Needs Analysis") || ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Decision Making")` as a single, cohesive unit. This is because `&&` has higher precedence than `||` (think of it like math, multiplication is done before addition, `&&` is done before `||`).

Comment: And I think this is an example of why I prefer using `AND()` and `OR()` over `&&` and `||`. There can still be some shenanigans around chaining `AND()`s and `OR()`s, but it would've been less prone to semantic error in this case.

Comment: Yes good point. Also, it's easier to line things up so you can see the logical structure.

Answer (score 2):

The heart of the issue here is that `&&` gets evaluated before `||`. `&&` has the higher precedence.

So instead of evaluating as you intended

- StageName is changing and
- StageName is 'Needs Analysis' or 'Decision Making'

The formula is being evaluated as

- StageName is changing and StageName is 'Needs Analysis'
- or StageName is 'Decision Making'

So this part of the formula would result in `true` if your StageName was `Decision Making`, regardless of whether StageName was changing or not.

Operator precedence, much like in math, determines what happens when a statement is *ambiguous* (i.e. it can be interpreted in more than one way).

You can override precedence using parenthesis (just like in math), but I'd argue that `AND()` and `OR()` would've been better to use here (as opposed to `&&` and `||`) because I think it's a more visual representation of how the evaluation will occur. That, and it'd be harder to make the same precedence mistake in this case.

```
AND(
    Record_Type_Name__c = "A",
    ISBLANK(Multipicklist_Field),
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Needs Analysis")
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Decision Making")
    )
)
```